# Create a rails controller which will update multiple tables in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails.
Can i create one controller which will take json data and update multiple table in db? this contoller will do nuthing in view.

I am doing the following:-
**routes.rb:**

```
post '/data' => 'data#submit'
```

**app/controllers/data_controller.rb:**

```
    class DataController < ApplicationController
       def submit
         data = JSON.parse request.body.read
         puts data
       end
    end
```

**then sending a post request**,

```
    RestClient.post "localhost:3000/submit_result", data.to_json, {:content_type => :json}
```

But this is gving error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant DataController)
```

Comment: Your URLs are inconsistent, /data and /submit_result. I assume this is an error in your post since the error message implies you hit the right route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a route in your config/routes.rb for it.

If you will only have that action, the definition will be something like

```
resource :data, only: [] do
  post :submit
end
```

`only: []` => This makes that the default CRUD actions not being created.

Then in your controller you can do the following:

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
   def submit
     data = JSON.parse params[:some_key]
     puts data
     render nothing: true # this will avoid view rendering
   end
end
```

Your rest client should do a call like this:

```
RestClient.post "localhost:3000/data/submit", data.to_json, {:content_type => :json}
```

About if you can update multiple tables from that controller: Yes, it is possible.

Suppose you send the data with the following format:

RestClient.post "localhost:3000/data/submit", {user: {name: 'John'}, role: {name: 'admins'} }.to_json, {:content_type => :json}

Then, in your controller you could create a user and a role, based on the received params:

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
   def submit
     User.create params[:user]
     Role.create params[:role]
     render nothing: true # this will avoid view rendering
   end
end
```

Anyway this might quickly complicate your controller's code. The best approach would be to create a new class receiving the params and creatign the stuff you need.

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
   def submit
     MassDataCreator.create(params)
     render nothing: true # this will avoid view rendering
   end
end
```

The benefit of this is that the controller code looks clearer, and you can write unit tests for the new class that creates the data (it's always easier to test a single class with unit testing than a controller through the integration tests)

Comment: Hi Fer, 
as per my understanding resource means its some table in db. data is not a table its a json data which contails entries for updating multiple tables.

Comment: The routes.rb only defines the mapping between your urls and the controller/action being called for a specific url. The models are the ones that have a table associated in the db.

Comment: Hi Fer,
after mkaing changes in routes and controller, i am getting error "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/data/submit"):"

Comment: Look at the example I wrote you. You should send the request to "localhost:3000/data/submit", or change the routes to submit_result and rename you controller method to submit_result

Comment: when i add 
resources :data, only[]
post '/data/submit' => 'data#submit'

It is giving error 
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant DataController)

Comment: You have to restart the server if you make any changes in the routes.rb file.

Comment: i have restarted the server still getting this error

Comment: I got the route cause of this error. spelling mistake in file name. my file name was data_controler.rb